# highslide: can I get multiple popups of the same html content?

Tags: html, highslide

I'm building a course site for my students, with different 'chapters' accessed from different links. I would like to be able to have two or more popups of the same page so I can view different parts of the same chapter side by side. Is this possible in highslide (I don't think it is...). Any solution, using highslide or not, would be appreciated!

Comment: A link to your site would help. Are you using inline HTML for the Highslide popup, or using an iframe in the popup? Highslide should have no problem opening multiple popups, as long as you don't dim the background, and have hs.allowMultipleInstances set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle demo that lets you open multiple HTML popups. In this case, both links are opening the same page of stuff, but that's just to keep the demo setup simple - normally you would have each link opening a different iframed page, but for your specific requirement, I guess you'd be opening the same page twice, just like this demo. Open the first link, then drag it by the header to one side, and open the second link.

http://jsfiddle.net/MisterNeutron/Qk6U6/1/

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Demo by MisterNeutron</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://highslide.com/highslide/highslide-full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://highslide.com/highslide/highslide.css">
<script type='text/javascript'>
hs.graphicsDir = 'http://highslide.com/highslide/graphics/';
hs.outlineType = 'rounded-white';
hs.wrapperClassName = 'draggable-header';
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a id="thumb1" href="http://highslide.com/examples/includes/include-short.htm" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe' } )">First iframe</a>
<br><br>
<a id="thumb2" href="http://highslide.com/examples/includes/include-short.htm" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe' } )">Second iframe</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, @MisterNeutron. What I'm chasing is the ability to open a second instance of the same popup from a single thumb link - click the link twice and get two identical popups.     This is not a common use case, I realise, but it can be quite useful in teaching to have some previously derived results visible next to the current part of the content that I'm explaining.    I can close a popup and re-open it again from the same link (no surprises there) so maybe highslide is keeping track of which link currently has an open popup?

Comment: Offhand, I can't think of any way to pull that off. Highslide "knows" that the popup from that link is already open, and won't try to open another one. And if you think about it, you can understand why. How would it know what to do when you closed one of them, for example?

Comment: Each anchor produces a uniquely-identified expander. There can be only expander per anchor. I think changing that would involve considerable rewriting of the script, but maybe someone else has a clever workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and informed response, @MisterNeutron. I do have a workaround that's a little more aesthetic than two adjacent redundant looking links: I can use a chapter heading as one link and a submenu under that with links to different sections within the chapter. Not exactly what I want but it'll work. This is my first use of highslide so I'm really a noob here. If I use a non-highslide link, I can open as many new browser instances as I want but these are totally different processes that take care of their own tidying up, I suppose. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Dreamweavers  menues to do give my site a dropdown list that I can then edit. Perhaps "open in new window" when you click the link will work.  I have found that most clicks will default to open in the same window.